# Yasnippet minor mode working in lisp-interaction-mode but not in emacs-lisp-mode

Tags: yasnippet

I wanted to test `yasnippet` for editing Emacs Lisp files. After installing it from the package manager, the problem is that it works fine from the `*scratch*` buffer but not when editing a Lisp file using `emacs-lisp-mode`.

To debug, I reduced my Emacs init file to one line:

```el
(setq debug-on-error t)
```

Then I started Emacs from command line with:

```
$ emacs test.el
```

and run `M-x yas-minor-mode` and then `M-x yas-reload-all`, then I typed
`defun` and pressed the `TAB` key, but nothing happend.

However, if I first switch to the `*scratch*` buffer and run the same commands it works fine and inserts the `defun` template when I press `TAB`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `yasnippet` doesn't define a "defun" snippet for `emacs-lisp-mode`. Instead, use the "def" snippet.

The reason you could use the "defun" snippet in the `*scratch*` buffer is because `lisp-interaction-mode` does have a "defun" snippet.
Look in the menu bar, under "YASnippet", you can find which snippets you can use.

To summarize: type `def` and press `TAB`.